# MongoDB - sum specific array element under conditions exclude duplicate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have a bunch of docs that look like below:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("8f30b453c2ece001364dc04d"), 
    "SessionId" : "awkuTQjj53kgqAZ4J", 
    "StartDate" : ISODate("2020-02-24T11:51:36.918+0000"), 
    "EndDate" : ISODate("2020-02-24T11:51:36.918+0000"), 
    "List1" : "X", 
    "List2" : "Y", 

    "rating" : [
        {
            "ObjectId" : "5d09e98380c5d5eb89ac5069", 
            "List" : "List 2", 
            "Rate" : NumberInt(5), 
            "RatedDate" : ISODate("2020-02-24T11:55:47.774+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "ObjectId" : "5d09e98380c5d5eb89ac5069", 
            "List" : "List 2", 
            "Rate" : NumberInt(4), 
            "RatedDate" : ISODate("2020-02-24T11:55:48.408+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "ObjectId" : "5d09e98380c5d5eb89ac505b", 
            "List" : "List 2", 
            "Rate" : NumberInt(3), 
            "RatedDate" : ISODate("2020-02-24T11:55:49.520+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "ObjectId" : "5d09e98380c5d5eb89ac505c", 
            "List" : "List 2", 
            "Rate" : NumberInt(3), 
            "RatedDate" : ISODate("2020-02-24T11:55:51.787+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "ObjectId" : "5d09e98380c5d5eb89ac5057", 
            "List" : "List 1", 
            "Rate" : NumberInt(4), 
            "RatedDate" : ISODate("2020-02-24T11:55:53.865+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "ObjectId" : "5d09e98380c5d5eb89ac5058", 
            "List" : "List 1", 
            "Rate" : NumberInt(4), 
            "RatedDate" : ISODate("2020-02-24T11:55:53.865+0000")
        }, 

    ], 
    "Answers" : {
        "SelectedList" : "1", 
    }, 

}
```

I  need to sum up all the rating.Rate where rating.List:'List 1' and respectively sum up all rating.Rate where rating.List:'List 2', also exclude duplicate records (by rating.ObjectId) and count only the ones with latest rating.RatedDate. I suppose this is a group aggregation.
Also they should match the criteria 
List1:'X' ,
Answers.selectedList:1
What I have written looks like below so far:

```
[
    { 
        "$match" : { 

        "List1" : "X", 
        "Answers.SelectedList" : "1"
    }
}, 
{ 
    "$unwind" : { 
        "path" : "$rating"
    }
}, 

{ 
    "$group" : { 
        "_id" : null, 
        "sum" : { 
            "$sum" : "$Rate"
        }
    }
}
]
```

can you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was a little confused around the List1/List2 however I think this will get you most of the way to your required aggregation query.

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "List1": "X",
            "Answers.SelectedList": "1"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind" : "$rating"
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: {
                id: "$rating.ObjectId",
                list: "$rating.List"
            },
            maxRatedDate: { $max: "$rating.RatedDate" },
            ratings: { $push:  "$rating" }
        }
    },{
        $addFields: {
            ratings: {
               $filter: {
                  input: "$ratings",
                  as: "item",
                  cond: { $eq: [ "$$item.RatedDate", "$maxRatedDate" ] }
               }
            }
         }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$ratings"
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id: "$ratings.List",
            sum : { 
                $sum : "$ratings.Rate"
            }
        }

    }
])
```

This will output the following

```
{ "_id" : "List 1", "sum" : 8 }
{ "_id" : "List 2", "sum" : 10 }
```

However, let's try to break it down.

To start with we've got a simple match, the same as yours in your question. this just limits the number of documents we pass back

```
$match: {
    "List1": "X",
    "Answers.SelectedList": "1"
}
```

Then we unwind all the array items so we get a document for each rating, this allows us to do some extra querying on the data.

```
{
    "$unwind" : "$rating"
}
```

Next, we've got a group by, here we're a group on the ObjectId of the rating so we can later remove duplicates, we're also finding out in the group which rating we've group has the highest date so we can take that one later in a projection. we're then pushing all the rating back in the array for later.

```
$group:{
    _id: {
        id: "$rating.ObjectId",
        list: "$rating.List"
    },
    maxRatedDate: { $max: "$rating.RatedDate" },
    ratings: { $push:  "$rating" }
}
```

Next we want to project the ratings array in to a single element in which it only contains the latest rating, for this we use a $filter on the array and filter them all out that don't match our max date we calculated in our previous step.

```
$addFields: {
    ratings: {
        $filter: {
            input: "$ratings",
            as: "item",
            cond: { $eq: [ "$$item.RatedDate", "$maxRatedDate" ] }
        }
    }
}
```

The next two steps are fairly simple and are just unwinding the array again (we've only got one element, then grouping them to get the total sum for the lists.

```
{
    $unwind: "$ratings"
},
{
    $group:{
        _id: "$ratings.List",
        sum : { 
            $sum : "$ratings.Rate"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Kevin Smith for such an analysis! I have a comment though.The identical key of my docs is the SessionId each doc has. So the goal is to sum up all the ratings.Rate per single rating.ObjectId per List ,(List1 or List2), and count only the ones with maxRatedDate to avoid duplicate rated rating.ObjectId for same List. In this case I added in Stage 3 `$group:{
    _id: {
    id:"$rating.ObjectId",
    list:"$rating.List",
    Session:"$SessionId"},
    maxRatedDate: { $max: "$rating.RatedDate" },
    ratings: { $push:  "$rating" }
    }` am I correct now?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct, you can just keep adding more things to the group by _id 

Comment: thank you so much @Kevin Smith you were really helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

At this point you only need to provide the `$group` stage with the field that you're actually grouping on as the `_id` field and reference the fields properly as they are still inside of the `rating` array:

```js
"$group" : { 
        "_id" : "$rating.List", 
        "sum" : { 
            "$sum" : "$rating.Rate"
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much, now I get some results but what about the duplicates? Some records have duplicate Rates on same rating.ObjectId  and the correct will be to keep just one that will be the last date (rating.RatedDate)